# AngularJS: $index lost with filter?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS so please be kind to me.. :-P

So I'm looping twice with *ng-repeat* as in this example:

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="b in aMSG">
        <p>{{b.name}}</p>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="c in b.x"><a ng-click="getM($parent.$index,$index)" href="#">{{c.name}}</a></i>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trK98/

But when I apply a *filter* to search for text within the children:

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="b in aMSG">
        <p>{{b.name}}</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search for?">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="c in b.x|filter:search"><a ng-click="getM($parent.$index,$index)" href="#">{{c.name}}</a></i>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

The *$index* is lost as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/zb2kc/

(search for instance for juice then click on it you'll see $index = 0)

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

P.S: Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: it's not lost, because your filtered array has only 1 item and juice is the first item.

Comment: I see. So how to point to the index in the not filtered array?

Comment: What do you need the `$index` for in this case?

Comment: I need it for another scope to use.

Comment: @pr.nizar: I don't know why you need to point to the original index. But you could try a trick with `ng-show` and use the original array.

Comment: Instead of using `ng-click="getM($parent.$index,$index)"`, why not pass in the actual objects to the function, eg: `ng-click="getM(b, c)"`

Comment: KhanhTO: _ng-show_ would make it too dirty!
@MWay: and how to get the index for those elements next (I mean the parent and the child)?

Comment: I think you could pass the object to the function as @MWay mentioned, and from there you could find out the index in the original array.

Comment: So I think I'll had to add some `id` (numbering lines) within the table to point to.. I thought of that too.. no better solution?

Comment: Thank you anyway guys! I've added an *id* for children as suggested by @MattWay. I think I'm still novice in AngularJS but I'll stick to that solution if you don't have better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use $index for any kind of logic. It can be used for managing CSS classes only. It's a highly volatile variable and will be changed after any change in source array (deletion, re-ordering), so $index is not bind to element of array, but only to position of *some* element in current *view* rendering.